# Parse steam inventory on PHP

Tags: php, steam, steam-web-api

Кто работал со steam API? Я пытаюсь спарсить инвентарь пользователя таким образом в PHP - file_get_contents('steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$id.'/inventory/json/730/…); Однако у steam есть лимит запросов (3 в минуту), если эти действия производить на сервере с Пользователями, то функционал поддерживаться не будет. Аналоги сайта парсят инвентарь через трейд-ссылку, которая использует сессию, сгенерированную один раз. Прошу помощи!

Comment: this is russin SO. Translate your question into russian language.

Comment: Привет! Кто работал со steam API? Я пытаюсь спарсить инвентарь пользователя таким образом в PHP - file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$id.'/inventory/json/730/2'); Однако у steam есть лимит запросов (3 в минуту), если эти действия производить на сервере с Пользователями, то функционал поддерживаться не будет. Аналоги сайта парсят инвентарь через трейд-ссылку, которая использует сессию, сгенерированную один раз. Прошу помощи!